# How do I create an alias for cmder to cd to project root?

Tags: bash, cmder

I have all my projects in a specific directory, say: `C:\users\myself\dev`
While working on a project, I often need to go into a deeper directory and then get back up to the root of the project. This can be a hassle so I am thinking about having an alias `~~` to go to the project root.

What would be a script (probably not a one liner?) to act as an alias to move me from any nested directory:

```
C:\users\myself\dev\[projectname]\any\path\down\the\project\dir
C:\users\myself\dev\[projectname]\possibly\also\here
```

back up to the immediate child of `dev`:

```
C:\users\myself\dev\[projectname]
```

**regardless of the project I am currently in**.

Not sure this is possible at all as I am blank on bash scripting. Probably not a oneliner.
Anyone in the know willing to share a script?

Comment: put alias in bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

Try entering this into your shell:

```
function up() {CD C:\users\myself\dev\"$@";}
```

To use it type :

```
up [projectname]
```

If it does what you want it to, find your `.bashrc` file and put this in it to make the function perminent.

This sets up a function called 'up' that will change directory to C:\users\myself\dev plus whatever you typed in after up. $@ is your arguments.

Comment: Thanks this gets me a bit closer, but ideally I would like to avoid typing the project name at all. It is in the pwd (the first child after `dev`) so it should suffice to say `up`

Comment: In that case... alias up="cd C:\user\myself\dev\projectname"

Comment: I probably wasn't specific enough in my description, will update it now. I want this to work in all possible projects